# Delphi/FireDAC/SQLite - force TEXT column affinity on a STRING type column (leading zeroes being lost)

Tags: sqlite, delphi, firedac

I did a mistake and declared a SQLite table column in `CREATE TABLE` DDL statement as `STRING`. Inserting `'00123'` into that column results as numeric value `123` being written (so leading zeroes are lost). I [now know](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html) I should have used `TEXT`.

Is there any way, using FireDAC, to somehow force `TEXT` affinity for that column without dropping and recreating the table? Or, in other words, force leading zeroes to be written in the `STRING` column type?

I've tried `INSERT INTO table_name (string_column) VALUES (CAST('00123' AS TEXT))` with no luck.

If drop/create table is the only way forward, is there a way to know for a table whether a column was created as `STRING` (so, get its affinity)?

-žarko

Comment: Unfortunately you will have to recreate table. Columns defined as a string can be found in `select sql from sqlite_master where name = 'table_name'`

Comment: The only way around I see is to store UTF-8 with `BLOB` affinity using BLOB literal: `INSERT INTO table_name (string_column) VALUES (x'3030313233')`.

Comment: Thanks @Branko and Peter Wolf - I ended up dropping and recreating the table with "text" type.

Comment: Your question answered my doubt in why zeros were not leading in my string since it is a string. I change its type to TEXT and solve my problem. Thanks.